# Is this following Separation of Concerns and PHP OOP standards?

Tags: php, object-oriented, pdo

I've been working with PHP for a while now, but unfortunately haven't delved into the OO side of it until recently.  I've been reading up on [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and OOP best practices, and I think I have an idea of what is expected, but there's always room to improve.  At any rate, is this heading in the right direction for PHP OOP?

**The Class (profile.php)**

```
<?php
$dbHost = "example.com";
$dbName = "exampleDB";
$user = "WouldntYou"; 
$password = "LikeToKnow";

//Get and parse the faculty name from the url
if(isset($_GET['facultyName'])) {
  $facultyName = explode("-", $_GET['facultyName']);
  $getFirstName = ucfirst($facultyName[1]);
  $getLastName = ucfirst($facultyName[0]);
}
else {
  $getFirstName = "";
  $getLastName = "";
}

class Employee {
  private $employeeId;
  private $firstName;
  private $middleName;
  private $lastName;
  private $suffix;
  private $eMail;
  private $phoneNumber;
  private $faxNumber;
  private $streetAddress;
  private $city;
  private $state;
  private $zipCode;
  private $profileWebsite;
  private $profilePhoto;
  private $jobName;
  private $departmentName;
  private $departmentURL;

  /** 
  * @desc combines first, middle, and last name along with suffix 
  * @param - n/a 
  * @return string - formatted name and title 
  */  
  public function display_name() {
    $fullName = $this->firstName;
    $fullName .= ($this->middleName!="") ? " " . $this->middleName . " " : " ";
    $fullName .= $this->lastName;
    $fullName .= ($this->suffix!="") ? ", " . $suffix : "";
    return $fullName;
  }

  /** 
  * @desc wraps email in anchor tag 
  * @param - n/a 
  * @return string - link to email
  */  
  public function display_email() {
    return "<a href='mailto:". $this->eMail . "'>". $this->eMail ."</a>";
  }

  /** 
  * @desc splits phone number, adds hyphens and parenthesis 
  * @param - n/a 
  * @return string - formatted phone number 
  */  
  public function display_phone() {
    return "(" . substr($this->phoneNumber, 0, 3) . ") " . substr($this->phoneNumber, 3, 3) . "-" . substr($this->phoneNumber, 6, 4);
  }

  /** 
  * @desc splits fax number, adds hyphens and parenthesis 
  * @param - n/a 
  * @return string - formatted fax number 
  */  
  public function display_fax() {
    return "(" . substr($this->faxNumber, 0, 3) . ") " . substr($this->faxNumber, 3, 3) . "-" . substr($this->faxNumber, 6, 4);
  }

  /** 
  * @desc wraps profilePhoto in image tag, using the display_name as alt text 
  * @param - n/a 
  * @return string - image tag 
  */  
  public function display_photo() {
    return "<img alt='". $this->display_name() . "' src='/profileImages/". $this->profilePhoto . "' class='profilePhoto'>";
  }

  /** 
  * @desc wraps profileWebsite in anchor tag 
  * @param - n/a 
  * @return string - link to profileWebsite
  */  
  public function display_website() {
    return "<a href='". $this->profileWebsite . "' target='_blank'>". $this->profileWebsite ."</a>";
  }

  /** 
  * @desc displays the complete address, wrapped in a p tag 
  * @param - n/a 
  * @return string - streetAddress, city, state, and zip code wrapped in p tag
  */  
  public function display_address() {
    return "<p>".$this->streetAddress."<br>".$this->city.", ".$this->state." ".$this->zipCode."</p>";
  }

  /** 
  * @desc Splits the jobTitle into an array, with "----" as delimiter 
  * @param - n/a 
  * @return array - each index contains a job title
  */  
  public function display_jobs() {
    return explode("----", $this->jobName);
  }

  /** 
  * @desc Splits the departmentName and departmentURL and creates a link, with "----" as delimiter 
  * @param - n/a 
  * @return array - each index contains a formed link with departmentName and departmentURL
  */  
  public function display_departments() {
    $deptName = explode("----", $this->departmentName);
    $deptURL = explode("----", $this->departmentURL);
    $deptLink = array(); 
    $count = 0;
    foreach($deptName as $name) {
        $deptLink[] = "<a href='$deptURL[$count]'>$name</a>";
        $count++;
    }
    return $deptLink;
  }
}

try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $user, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT employeeId, firstName, middleName, lastName, suffix, eMail, phoneNumber, faxNumber, streetAddress, city, state, zipCode, profileWebsite, profilePhoto, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT jobName ORDER BY jobTitleId SEPARATOR "----") AS jobName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT departmentName ORDER BY departmentId SEPARATOR "----") AS departmentName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT departmentURL ORDER BY departmentId SEPARATOR "----") AS departmentURL
                       FROM employee 
                       INNER JOIN employee_has_jobTitle ON employeeId = employee_has_jobTitle.employee_employeeId 
                       INNER JOIN jobTitle ON employee_has_jobTitle.jobTitle_jobTitleId = jobTitleId 
                       INNER JOIN employee_has_department ON employee.employeeId = employee_has_department.employee_employeeId
                       INNER JOIN department ON employee_has_department.department_departmentId = departmentId
                       WHERE firstName = :firstName AND lastName = :lastName AND employeeId <> 9');
/* <> 9?!?  Yeah, I don't want people to be able to view my profile :) */
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Employee');
$stmt->execute(array('firstName'=>$getFirstName,'lastName'=>$getLastName));

$employee = $stmt->fetch();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Oops! " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Wow, that's a HUGE class.  At least it seems that way to me, but I'm no pro.  Is that too long?  How should it be split if so?  Is this me doing a whole bunch of procedural code, wrapping it in a class, and deeming it OOP, or am I on the right track?  Just a few of my concerns there.

**The Display Page**

```
<?php
include 'includes/phpScripts/profile.php';

$title = "--- Profile: " . $employee->display_name();
$description = "--- Profile: " . $employee->display_name();

include 'includes/headerFooters/mainHeader.php';

?>

<div id="columnContainer">
  <div id='centerColumn'>
    <h1><?=$employee->display_name();?></h1>

    <?=$employee->display_photo();?>

    <div class='contactContainer'>
      <?php
        foreach($employee->display_departments() as $dept) {
          echo "<h3>$dept</h3>";
        }
      ?>

      <p>
        <?php 
          $firstJob = true;
          foreach($employee->display_jobs() as $job) {
            if($firstJob) {
              $firstJob = false;
            }
            else {
              echo ", ";
            }
            echo $job; 
          }
        ?>
      </p>

      <p>
        <strong>Phone: </strong><?=$employee->display_phone();?><br>
        <strong>Fax: </strong><?=$employee->display_fax();?><br>
        <strong>E-mail: </strong><br><?=$employee->display_email();?>
      </p>

      <p><?=$employee->display_address();?></p>

      <div class='clearfix'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  ...
</div>

<?php include('includes/headerFooters/mainFooter.php'); ?>
```

I created this layout while I was still a student, and I look at the code now and cringe.  I've recently been reading about [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) and [not using `id` for styling](http://css-tricks.com/a-line-in-the-sand/), but with hundreds of pages involved, we can't invest the time for a (much needed) redesign just yet.  However, am I separating out the PHP enough here, or should more things be done inside the class methods (the for loops, adding the comma, etc)?

My apologies for the extremely long code, I expect some tl;dr.  However, am I on the right track for OOP, or do I need to hit the books, and Google, a bit more?

Once I get a few good habits, I'll be diving into Laravel 4.  Let me know if I'm ready for it, and thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot that could be improved, so just a few remarks.

1.) Configuration should be put into separate file.

```
$dbHost = "example.com";
$dbName = "exampleDB";
$user = "WouldntYou";
$password = "LikeToKnow";
```

It is better to use constants for configuration, so their values can't be overwritten.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'example.com');
define('DB_NAME', 'exampleDB');
define('DB_USER', 'WouldntYou');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'LikeToKnow');
```

2.) You should do some validation of input and you should initialise your variables, with initialisation you will get rid of unnecessary `else` block as well.

Original code:

```
if(isset($_GET['facultyName'])) {
    $facultyName = explode("-", $_GET['facultyName']);
    $getFirstName = ucfirst($facultyName[1]);
    $getLastName = ucfirst($facultyName[0]);
}
else {
    $getFirstName = "";
    $getLastName = "";
}
```

Updated code:

```
$getFirstName = '';
$getLastName  = '';
if (array_key_exists('facultyName', $_GET)){
    $facultyName = explode("-", $_GET['facultyName']);

    if (count($facultyName) == 2 && strlen($facultyName[0]) && strlen($facultyName[1])){
        $getFirstName = ucfirst($facultyName[1]);
        $getLastName = ucfirst($facultyName[0]);
    }
}
```

3.) Class should be defined in a separate file, so it can be used elsewhere.

4.) In your class there is unuses attribute `private $employeeId;`.

5.) In method `display_name` there is undeclared variable `$suffix`, you should always initialize your variables before using them.

6.) You are using class attributes, but you are not setting them anywhere, they all containg `null` value.

7.) You should set class attributes in __constructor or via `setAttributeName($attributeName)` methods.

8.) If you are accessing attributes from outside of class you should do it via `getAttribtueName()` methods.

9.) You are creating HTML inside class, it is better to use MVC pattern.

10.) In your SQL query you are using hard coded value 9, the value should be in configuration.

11.) The SQL query is overly complex, you should think about if it can be simplified, the query will be probably very slow with more rows in the tables.

12.) You put too much to `try {...} catch(...) {...}` block, you should put your database connection and query execution into separate blocks.

13.) Your PHPDoc comments are wrong:

Original:

```
/**
 * @desc Splits the jobTitle into an array, with "----" as delimiter
 * @param - n/a
 * @return array - each index contains a job title
 */
```

Updated:

```
/**
 * Splits the jobTitle into an array, with "----" as delimiter
 *     
 * @return array Each index contains a job title.
 */
```

If there are no parameters then don't use any `@param` in documentation. Do not use `-` here `@return array - each ...`.

14.) If you use `""` for wrapping strings then PHP interpreter will look into those strings and search for variables, if you use `''` then PHP interpreter won't need to do that.

15.) You are using unnecessary semicolon in single line PHP code `<?=$employee->display_name();?>`, can be written like this `<?= $employee->display_name() ?>`, it is common to leave out semicolon in one line PHP code.

16.) In view files it is more readable to use alternative PHP syntax:

Original:

```
<?php
foreach($employee->display_departments() as $dept) {
    echo "<h3>$dept</h3>";
}
?>
```

Updated:

```
<? foreach($employee->display_departments() as $dept) : ?>
    <h3><?= $dept ?></h3>
<? endforeach ?>
```

17.) You should read about MVC design pattern and try to implement it, or even better to use some PHP Framework like Symfony2, Laravel or something similar.

Comment: Very well laid out, thank you!  The class attributes are set when the query is fetched.  Should I put the query in the constructor, or leave it where it is and just put it in a different `try`?  As for the complex query, should that be split into multiple queries?  There are 5 tables showing, but I actually need to join a few more for education and biographical background information.  Diving into Laravel 4 with my next project, in the process of setting up the server in my spare time.  Trying to understand OOP better in the mean time.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: Also, should the `$_GET` processing be placed into the config file too, or on the display page?

Comment: Sorry to pepper you with more questions.  Last one, I promise!  Until I move into MVC, where should the HTML be formatted?

Comment: You can leave the SQL query where it is, but you should move the Employee class into separate file, so it can be reused somewhere else. Regarding the query it does not necessarily mean to split the query into more queries, but if it can be simplified (for example by changing table structure and table relations) then it should be simplified.

Comment: I'll look in to that then.  So the `$_GET` processing and query in one file, the config in another, and then a file for the class?

Comment: Regarding `$_GET`, in configuration there should be mostly static values, it is quite unusual to have there something that comes from URL. Processing of inputs (like validation etc.) should not be done in views (your display page) but somewhere else, if it was MVC pattern then it would be in C or M. HTML should be formatted in the display page.

Comment: Yes, 1 class per file (or 1 class + related exception), config another file, displaying HTML another file, processing requests / executing queries another file(s).

Answer (score 2):

Your `profile.php` file is doing way too much. A good test to see if you are adhering to the Separation of Concerns principle is: Do one thing, and do it well.

It seems `profile.php` is doing the following things:

1. Gathering information from the HTTP request params
2. Defining a "model" class called `Employee`
3. The `Employee` class is formatting HTML
4. The bottom of the file is querying the database for the Employee record

You should read up on the [Model-View-Controller programming pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=model+view+controller&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb). Since you are writing PHP, check out [PHP Objects, Patterns and Practices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/143022925X). It's a great read about OOP in PHP and how you can apply many of the common programming patterns.

Comment: I've read quite a bit on MVC, and will be diving into it via the Laravel framework on my next project.  I wanted to get a better grasp on OOP prior to that though.  A few questions, If I may.  Where should I be processing the HTTP requests?  I originally had it at the top of the display page, but I was trying to keep as much of the PHP out of there as possible.  Where should I be formatting the HTML, if not in the class methods?  Also, where should the database query be located?  Thanks for the quick response and input, plus one!

Comment: These questions will get answered by diving into MVC. The essence of Separation of Concerns can be boiled down to a couple statements: Do one thing and do it well; Favor composition over inheritance. Your specific code example is hard because to follow Separation of Concerns is to implement MVC.